# Find rows which have different attribute value in ONE day for same product. (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

can someone help me to write a query?

I have for example columns:

Date
product_key
category_code

In one day I expect to have same category_code for one product, but I want to check this with SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use `EXISTS()` (and possibly `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can `group` your results by date and product, and use `count` and `distinct` to find if there is more than one category code for a product. You can then filter rows `having` more than 1 distinct category in the group.

```
SELECT
    Date, product_key, count(distinct category_code) AS categories
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    Date, product_key
HAVING
    count(distinct category_code) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the day, the product_key and the category_code that doubles, You should use query like this:

```
SELECT
  date,
  product_key,
  category_code,
  count(1)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, product_key, category_code
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```